# Strange behavior with atof

Tags: floating-point, c-strings, atof

I have an Arduino which receives a message from my smartphone (over bluetooth) containing the unix timestamp. Now, i am trying to sync my DS1307 with that timestamp.

However, it did not work, hence, i begun searching and found some strange behavior upon converting the C-style array containing the timestamp to a float number.

```
// Copy the time into "timeBuff"
int timeLength = siz - _CAT_LENGTH_;
char timeBuff[timeLength+1];
memcpy(timeBuff, &msg[_CAT_LENGTH_], timeLength);
timeBuff[timeLength] = '\0';

// For debugging
Serial.print(F("timeBuff:   "));
Serial.println(timeBuff);

// Convert timeBuff string into a variable of type long
float deviceTime = atof(timeBuff);

// Now, deviceTime != what we printed above
Serial.print(F("Epoch time: "));
Serial.println(deviceTime);
```

The first 5 lines copy the right part of the message into a character array, and adds the termination zero.

Afterwards, we print the content of `timeBuff` and convert it to a `float` which is stored in `deviceTime`. Finally, we print `deviceTime`.

This was the result of my first test

```
timeBuff:   1476113620
Epoch time: 1476113664.00
```

And this of the second test

```
timeBuff:   1476115510
Epoch time: 1476115456.00
```

**Why does the result of `atof` differ from the string we passed it?**

Comment: `float` doesn't have enough precision to represent the value exactly.

Comment: Why are you dealing with `float` here ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I need to sync my DS1307 (RTC clock for Arduino), hence, i need to create a `DateTime` which i pass to the library's `adjust` method. To create that `DateTime` i wanted to pass the unix timestamp i received in the message.

Comment: @HyperZ You don't need float. Simpy use `long` instead of `float` and `atol` instead of `atof`. BTW what is `adjust`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks! I should have knew to stay away from float.. :)

Comment: @MichaelWalz `adjust` is just some method to set a `RTC_DS1307` object to a given time, on Arduino.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On most platforms `float` is represented in IEEE-754 single-precision format, which is 32-bit floating point format with 24-bit (23+1) significand. It simply does not have enough precision to represent your numbers. Your numbers require about 32 bits to represent. Integer values wider than 24 bits will generally lose precision when stored in `float`.

The loss of precision will manifest itself as loss of trailing bits with rounding in the last remaining bit

```
1476113620 -> ‭01010111111110111011010011010100‬
1476113664 -> ‭01010111111110111011010100000000‬
```

Comment: Detail: "Integer values wider than 23 bits" --> off by 1.  IEEE-754 single-precision type can exactly represent all positive/negative 24-bit integer values.  IOWs all `int25_t` and `uint24_t`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, i am a bit confused why they mention `float (32 bit) - signed number from -3.4028235E38 to 3.4028235E38` on https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/data-types-in-arduino

Comment: @AnT Okay, thanks for your help! I will have to read some more about floating points i guess :)

Comment: "Less and less"?  You mean "more and more (sparse)" or "less and less dense"?

Comment: @HyperZ: It is the correct range from min to max. But that does not mean that every number in that range can be represented - that would be impossible. Floating-point format provide more denisty around 0 and get more and more sparse as you move away from it. At certain point away from 0 you begin losing integers. With your values, you are already way into that territory.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple program that illustrates the same issue even more clearly, stripping away any complications involving timestamps or `atof()`, which turn out to be irrelevant:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float  f = 1234567890.;
    double d = 1234567890.;
    printf("f = %f\n", f);
    printf("d = %f\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

I encourage you to compile this little program and run it.  When I do, I see:

```
f = 1234567936.000000
d = 1234567890.000000
```

At first this seems impossible.  It looks like it's got to be a bug in the compiler, or in `printf`, or something.  If I assign the simple number "1234567890" to the variable `f`, how can it not print out that way? And the answer is, *because type `float` does not have enough precision*.

Everybody understands that limited precision means that you might not be able to represent a number like 1.234567890 exactly, that it might get mangled into 1.234567936 or something.  And the key thing to recognize here is that any floating-point type (`float` *or* `double` or anything else) has a limited number of digits of significance, period.  It's not just digits of precision to the right of the decimal point that matters.  For big numbers, you can't even represent all the digits to the left of the decimal point precisely, either.  (As a matter of fact, this point -- that you have a limited amount of precision, that applies on either side of the decimal point -- is what the word "floating" in "floating point" actually *means*.)

Comment: One note: Since the question is about Arduino, the results will be the same for `float` *and* for `double` there. In Arduino, `sizeof(float) == sizeof(double) == 4` (at least by default; there is an option to have 64-bit `double`s, but those are going to be even slower than `float`).

Comment: @TimČas Oh, my.  Thanks.  (I wonder if that even meets the C standard?  My vague memory is that `double` is required to have the equivalent of at least ~10 decimal digits worth of precision.)

Comment: Hmm ... possibly. `DECIMAL_DIG` is specified in terms of the *widest* supported type (I assume at least `long double` is 64-bit there, so that *would* conform) ... but `DBL_DIG < 10` violates both C89 (2.4.2.2; par. unknown) *and* C99 (5.2.4.2.2p9)! That said, Arduino is C++, not C, so *maybe* things are different there (I doubt it, since C++98 is C89-based, but still)? In either case, if it is non-compliant, it would mean that while one *shouldn't have had to* worry about `double` not having enough precision, one still has to in practice in this case.